# Call Class or Activity When Successful URL is loaded in webview

Tags: android, webview, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am Successful intrigate PayUMoney Payment Gateway In My App. I want to call one class or Activity if Successfully Payment Done. And if Payment Was Failed This class or Activity Does not Call. I was trying lot of things but nothing is work for me.
    PayUMoneyActivity.java

```
package com.payumoneywebviewintri;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class PayUMoneyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String merchant_key = "OygoFs";
String salt = "BV1QBwCv";
String action1 = "";
String base_url = "https://test.payu.in";
// int error = 0;
// String hashString = "";
// Map<String, String> params;
String txnid = "";
String amount = "1";
String productInfo = "";
String firstName = "Basit";
String emailId = "abdulbasitkhan88@gmail.com";

private String SUCCESS_URL = "http://er.16mb.com/success.php";
private String FAILED_URL = "http://er.16mb.com/failure.php";
private String phone = "7817857472";
private String serviceProvider = "payu_paisa";
private String hash = "";

Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private WebView webView;


@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_umoney);
    // getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
 //     webView = new WebView(this);
 //   setContentView(webView);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wb);
    JSONObject productInfoObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray productPartsArr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject productPartsObj1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject paymentIdenfierParent = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray paymentIdentifiersArr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject paymentPartsObj1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject paymentPartsObj2 = new JSONObject();
    try {
        // Payment Parts
        productPartsObj1.put("name", "abc");
        productPartsObj1.put("description", "abcd");
        productPartsObj1.put("value", "1");
        productPartsObj1.put("isRequired", "true");
        productPartsObj1.put("settlementEvent", "EmailConfirmation");
        productPartsArr.put(productPartsObj1);
        productInfoObj.put("paymentParts", productPartsArr);

        // Payment Identifiers
        paymentPartsObj1.put("field", "CompletionDate");
        paymentPartsObj1.put("value", "05/08/2016");
        paymentIdentifiersArr.put(paymentPartsObj1);

        paymentPartsObj2.put("field", "TxnId");
        paymentPartsObj2.put("value", txnid);
        paymentIdentifiersArr.put(paymentPartsObj2);

        paymentIdenfierParent.put("paymentIdentifiers",
                paymentIdentifiersArr);
        productInfoObj.put("", paymentIdenfierParent);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    productInfo = productInfoObj.toString();

    Log.e("TAG", productInfoObj.toString());

    Random rand = new Random();
    String rndm = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt())
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
    txnid = hashCal("SHA-256", rndm).substring(0, 20);

    hash = hashCal("SHA-512", merchant_key + "|" + txnid + "|" + amount
            + "|" + productInfo + "|" + firstName + "|" + emailId
            + "|||||||||||" + salt);

    action1 = base_url.concat("/_payment");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                                       SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "SslError! " + error,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "Page Started! " + url,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (url.equals(SUCCESS_URL)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this,TestActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "Success! " + url,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "Failure! " + url,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
        //
        // @Override
        // public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        //
        // Toast.makeText(PayMentGateWay.this, "" + url,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // }
    });

    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(PayUMoneyActivity.this),
            "PayUMoney");
    Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapParams.put("key", merchant_key);
    mapParams.put("hash", hash);
    mapParams.put("txnid", txnid);
    mapParams.put("service_provider", "payu_paisa");
    mapParams.put("amount", amount);
    mapParams.put("firstname", firstName);
    mapParams.put("email", emailId);
    mapParams.put("phone", phone);

    mapParams.put("productinfo", productInfo);
    mapParams.put("surl", SUCCESS_URL);
    mapParams.put("furl", FAILED_URL);
    mapParams.put("lastname", "");

    mapParams.put("address1", "");
    mapParams.put("address2", "");
    mapParams.put("city", "");
    mapParams.put("state", "");

    mapParams.put("country", "");
    mapParams.put("zipcode", "");
    mapParams.put("udf1", "");
    mapParams.put("udf2", "");

    mapParams.put("udf3", "");
    mapParams.put("udf4", "");
    mapParams.put("udf5", "");
    // mapParams.put("pg", (empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"))) ?
    // ""
    // : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"));
    webview_ClientPost(webView, action1, mapParams.entrySet());

}

public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                mHandler = null;
             //   Toast.makeText(PayMentGateWay.this, "Success",
                    //    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
public void webview_ClientPost(WebView webView, String url,
                               Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> postData) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("<html><head></head>");
    sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
    sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>",
            url, "post"));
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
        sb.append(String.format(
                "<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />",
                item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
    }
    sb.append("</form></body></html>");
 //   Log.d(tag, "webview_ClientPost called");
    webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
}

public boolean empty(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.trim().equals(""))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public String hashCal(String type, String str) {
    byte[] hashseq = str.getBytes();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(hashseq);
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();

        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1)
                hexString.append("0");
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
    }
    return hexString.toString();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webviewPayment.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webviewPayment.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
                {
                    dialog.show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(webviewPayment, url);
                    if (dialog.isShowing())
                        dialog.dismiss();

                   if(url.equals(SUCCESS_URL))
                   {
                       if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                           new GetBookSeatOperation().execute();

                       }

                       else {
                           Toaster.make(getActivity(), R.string.err_went_wrong );

                       }                       }

                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            //   }
    } else {
        Toaster.make(getActivity(), R.string.err_went_wrong);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood, but you could simply use

```
mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class);
```

Comment: but I want going this activity or class  if and only if my Payment was successful.that for where to call class .or activity in my all code i don't know .

Comment: Don't you know how to check if the payment was done?

Comment: here is two url .success url and failed url . i don't know which part of my code cause successful url or which part cause failed url . that for i don't know where  to call class when my successful url is loaded on the screen